# Automatic update on Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Is there any app that has the feature where we list down the Facebook posts that we want to update and then we set time for it as well and then it updates that post automatically on the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HootSuite](http://hootsuite.com/) is a social media dashboard app that, among other functionality, lets you schedule Facebook (and Twitter) updates to be posted at times you set within the app. It should do what you want.

This functionality is included in the free version for up to 5 Facebook profiles - if you want more than 5 profiles you'll need to upgrade to one of their paid plans.

Comment: You can also try Buffer (bufferapp.com)